# Upload Django app to Heroku. ModuleNotFoundError:No Module named 'Name of Project"

Tags: django

I can not upload Django App to Heroku by command: git push heroku master. After uploading I have error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bot_diller'

Procfile:
web: gunicorn bot_diller.wsgi --log-file -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDn59.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the directory structure the root of your Git project is not entirely clear to me.
It seems you reference `bot_diller` as python module probably in an import statement in one of your Python files, which is outside of the scope of the code you push to Heroku.

The Django project seems to be inside `bot_diller/new_project`, where you have the top-level files like `Procfile`, `requirements.txt` and `manage.py`.

The Django app you created seems to be called `main`,  which is also a Python module and beside that you have a module named `new_project`, which probably contains the Django settings.

So inside your Django project you can write import statements like

`from main.models import MyModel`

and the import error probably originates from a statement like

`from bot_diller.new_project.main.models import MyModel`

Comment: Sorry, You answered So inside your Django project you can write import statements like? on which folder? settings?

Comment: Based on your current folder structure in the Python files inside `bot_diller/new_project` you should write imports like `from main.models import MyModel`